# Silverght 5 system.unauthorizedaccessexception

Tags: c#, silverlight

Hi i am trying obtain the content of a text file on C:\pruebas\datos.txt 
I have a project of Silverlight 5, inside the project i've a button and a TextBlock. In the buttonclick event handler I put the following code and never work. I check IntelliTrace and tells me which a system.unauthorizedaccessexception  occurs.

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client;
        client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, a) =>
        {
            if (a.Error == null )
            {
                Result = a.Result;
                txtDownloadedText.Text = Result;
            }
        };

        client.BaseAddress = "";
        client.DownloadStringAsync(
            new Uri(@"C:\pruebas\datos.txt"));
    }
```

Comment: Does your Silverlight application have elevated trust?  If not, this is exactly the behaviour I would expect.

Comment: I add a manifest to the project, and add the next line: 
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />
Still not work @LukeWoodward

Comment: @LukeWoodward is right, your application needs to either be OOB or have elevated trust to perform this operation.

Comment: @DNKROZ what means OOB ?

Comment: It means out of browser - a silverlight application what is run stand alone and cannot be accessed from a browser. An OOB application has elevated permissions and can perform tasks that are blocked on an in-broswer silverlight app, in your case - accessing a file content. (See this for info on how to enable OOB http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833073%28v=vs.95%29.aspx )                                     (and this for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721%28v=vs.95%29.aspx )